# Django: import Topic Issue, word Topic shows instead of title?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hey guys I just began working through the Django section in the Python Crash Course. I'm making a learning log in which you can add entries. I followed the book but I'm having one odd issue. When I add a new topic instead of the title for a new topic I literally get the word Topic

[image: Topic Issue]

My code is so far as follows, under admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from learning_logs.models import Topic 

admin.site.register(Topic)
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about """
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def _str_(self):
        """Returns a  string representation of the model """
        return self.text
```

the code matches the book, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need two underscores for the str method, not one:

```
# No
def _str_(self):
   pass

# Yes
def __str__(self):
   pass
```

Comment: Thank you. What would you suggest be the best way of learning Django? I get thrown off since idk where the author gets the classes and models and such things

Comment: The Django documentation's tutorial is great - easy to follow and goes over everything you need: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/